# How to load CSV file in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to load CSV file in logstash but it is not reading the file and not creating the index in elasticsearch
I need to read the CSV file in elasticsearch. 
Tried few changes in config file.

My Config file

```
input {
    file {
        type => "csv"
        path => "/root/installables/*.csv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => localhost
        index => "client"
    }
}
```

Could anybody tell how to load CSV file in logstash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should put a "csv" filter. I make it work like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/filepath..."
    start_position => beginning
    # to read from the beginning of file
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["COL1", "COL2"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        index => "csv_index"
    }
}
```

Also, adding stdout as output helps you to debug and know if the file is loading

Comment: what is sincedb? and why do we need to mention it?

Comment: and do I need to install CSV plugin and if yes then how?

Comment: logstash store the offset of the files read in a folder named .sincedb. Setting to null forces to reprocess all files.

Comment: CSV filter is part of logstash distribution https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html

Comment: Nope it didn't create the index in ES. The path of sincedb is same or will be something else?

Comment: It should be the same (it's a system path). Do you get any output in your terminal?

Comment: Nope I was checking in ES, no idea how to check in terminal for logstash, I am new to logstash

Comment: If you add the "stdout { codec => rubydebug }" line, you should see the output in the stdout (and also in ES if it works)

Comment: I already added that the current config file is input {
file {
path => ["\root\installables\POI_1433831220000.CSV"]
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
}

filter {
csv {
columns => ["NBN_SITE_CODE","POI_SITE_NAME","POI_LNG","POI_LAT","POI_STATE","IPACT_EXTRACTION_TIME"]
separator => ","
}
}

output {

elasticsearch {
hosts => localhost
#protocol => "http"
index => "test"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
~

Comment: I am running logstash by systemctl start logstash.service

Comment: then you should find the service logs into /var/log and check if it is working ok

Comment: I tried the configurations shared and they worked fine. What if I need to print the values of col1 and col2 in the stdout? I tried output {
    stdout { "COL1", "COL2" }
} but this gives an error. Can you please help with this too?